# SpecFlow issue - Before Scenario/Feature looping through multiple times

Tags: selenium-webdriver, specflow

Any one else having this issue?

I have used `[Scope(Feature = "FeatureName")]` at the top of my steps so that only these steps are usable for that feature. I have then used a `[BeforeScenario("taggedScenario")]`. Multiple tests have the same tag so i would expect this to be run each time before each of the tagged tests. However when i go to run a single test it runs through the before scenario multiple times before the starting. I would expect it to run once, then run my test. If I was to run 2 tests with the same tag i would then expect it to run the before scenario before each test.

Has anyone else come across this issue and if so has anyone managed to resolve it?

Comment: do your step classes inherit from base classes which contain these `BeforeScenario` hooks?

Comment: No, they don't inherit from any other class

Comment: @VincentHoward Could you please open an issue here https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow with an example? Thanks!

Comment: @SamHolder why won't this work with inheritance? (I'm currently using a base class which I would like to use for this)

Comment: Specflow steps are global so inheritance of classes which have the `[binding]` attribute is unnecessary, and causes airflow to add each method twice, so you'll get two before scenario methods